# Not able to achieve dark mode using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

```
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
    }
}
```

I am using the above code to achieve dark mode on my demo project but its not working.
 Any help or insight would be really appreciated.

Comment: you are using right colors in a project? is switch in debugger working?

Comment: Yes @Lu_, working in debugger

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dark mode in SwiftUI Preview doesn't have a dark background with Xcode 11.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912203/dark-mode-in-swiftui-preview-doesnt-have-a-dark-background-with-xcode-11-4)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dark mode is half working in previews, it just forgets to draw the background.

The following workaround allows you to add `.darkModeFix()` to your `ContentView()` in your preview function. You can optionally add `false` as a parameter to switch off dark mode.

```
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
                .darkModeFix()
        }
    }
}
```

Just add the following somewhere in your project:

```
public struct DarkView<Content> : View where Content : View {
    var darkContent: Content
    var on: Bool
    public init(_ on: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.darkContent = content()
        self.on = on
    }

    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if on {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                darkContent.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.black).colorScheme(.dark)
            } else {
                darkContent
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    public func darkModeFix(_ on: Bool = true) -> DarkView<Self> {
        DarkView(on) {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This seems to be a bug in Xcode 11.0 beta. A temporary workaround is to wrap your content inside a `NavigationView`.

For example, the following code will not take effect in dark mode preview:

```
var body: some View {
  Text("Hello World")
}
```

But after wrapping the content in a `NavigationView`, dark mode preview works as expected:

```
var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    Text("Hello World")
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is still an issue in Xcode 11.3.

Comment: Still an issue in Xcode 11.5

Comment: The same on Xcode 11.7

Answer (score 8):

**It fixed the preview, but doesn't change my code**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ZStack {
                Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                ContentView().environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)

            }
            ContentView().environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A bug apparently. Even doing `MyView().colorScheme(.dark)` isn't working.
Context-click (right click, or Ctrl-click) the 'play' button (which you use to simulate running your app). Click Debug Preview. Open the Debug area. Then, you can use the Enviroment Overrides to configure things like dark/light mode, dynamic type, accessibility settings etc.

BTW, to open the Enviroment Overrides settings go to just above the debugger and press this button:
[image: Env overrides look similar to a toggle switch]