# Dark mode in SwiftUI Preview doesn't have a dark background with Xcode 11.4

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Does anyone have the same problem, that Xcode (11.4) doesn't show a dark background, when previewing in dark mode?

Steps to reproduce:

1) Create a new project, a `Single View App`

2) Add the `.environment`-modifier to the preview:

```
Group {
    ContentView()
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
    ContentView()
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
}
```

You get this result:

[image: Xcode preview]

Comment: Maybe that helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591669/not-able-to-achieve-dark-mode-using-swiftui/56593027#56593027

Comment: The current accepted answer is out of date, so I think mine should be the accepted one now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
public struct DarkView<Content> : View where Content : View {
    var darkContent: Content
    var on: Bool
    public init(_ on: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.darkContent = content()
        self.on = on
    }

    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if on {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                darkContent.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.black).colorScheme(.dark)
            } else {
                darkContent
            }
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension View {
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    public func darkModeFix(_ on: Bool = true) -> DarkView<Self> {
        DarkView(on) {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
yourView()
.environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
                    .darkModeFix()
```

Comment: Thanks! But why the `var on: Bool`? This property is completely useless ;)

Answer (score 20):

Setting `\.colorScheme` in the environment is deprecated, so instead use the `.preferedColorScheme` modifier. For example,

```
ContentView()
    .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
```

Comment: How have I not seen this before? I just went through a bunch of effect implementing my own custom function for adding a dark mode to a view.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Everything else, assuming it works, is overkill; especially for a preview mode.

Answer (score 0):

As [m-reza-f](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3815069/m-reza-f) mentioned in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591669/not-able-to-achieve-dark-mode-using-swiftui/56593027#56593027), this is a bug in Xcode (which is still active as this answer is posted).

I'll add that instead of wrapping your actual `body` code in a `NavigationView`, you can simply wrap the `previews` code in your `PreviewProvider` in a `NavigationView` instead, to achieve the same results:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
     Group {
          NavigationView {
               ContentView()
                    .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
          }

          NavigationView {
               ContentView()
                    .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Looks like [Austin Conlon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62255126/2828617) is probably more appropriate since it actually solves the problem. First time I've seen it as a suggested solution!